# Наследовать объявленный ранее класс

Tags: python, классы, ооп

Есть `__init__.py`, который подгружает (`from ploader import *`) python-сценарий `ploader.py`.
В `ploader.py` подгружаются другие классы. Так вот, вопрос собственно в том,
как в сценариях (которые подгружает `ploader.py`) расширять уже объявленные классы.

Например, в ploader объявлен класс `CommonThread`, который далее будет необходим во всех 
сценариях, так как они должны его расширять.
Такое вообще возможно?

Пробовал посредством:

```
class MyThread(CommonThread) ...
```

Говорит, что нет такого класса (`CommonThread`) и нечего наследовать.

Comment: Не очень понял: в каких модулях нужно расширять - в импортирующих ploader.py или импортируемых в него?

Comment: Я думаю, вам стоит закинуть на pastbin.com код и привести его здесь, а то не очень понятно.

Comment: наверно я многое запутанно пояснил.Получается, что есть __init__.py, он будет запускать программу и импортировать в себя ploader.py (загрузчик необходимых модулей).Модули я планировал описывать в ini-файле, точнее с него считывать название модуля и параметры для импорта.Есть класс CommonThread - который определяет последующие классы-модули, которые должны его наследовать. Но, так как я его объявляю в ploader.py , а лишь потом импортирую последующие классы-модули - появляется проблема, пишет что нет такого класса:

class MyThread(CommonThread)
---
NameError: name 'CommonThread' is not defined

Comment: @akm74, просто приведите кусок кода, где ваша проблема воспроизводится.

Comment: -----------------
startinng_app.py:

....

# Подгружаем класс loader:
path.append(getcwd()+"/plugins")
from __loader import Loader

....
-----------------
__loader.py

from __common_thread import *
from os import getcwd, path

...

path.append(getcwd()+"/plugins")
from __loader import CommonThread,Loader

...

# здесь инициализируем полученный плагин-класс

...
-----------------
файл класса плагина:

...

class CheckSender(CommonThread):

....

Comment: а что значат троеточия? а то у меня голова закружилась

Comment: то что между троеточиями - содержание скрипта..
может кто знает где прочитать про подобное или дадут ссылку - был бы очень рад.

Если я всё правильно понимаю - то это нечто схожее с php.
То есть класс объявлен в одном файле, например в файле - class.php , а наследуется в файле extend_class.php . При таком формате если я в файле index.php делаю include("class.php"); а затем - include("extend_class.php"); - то мы можем спокойно наследовать класс.

Как подобное можно реализовать в Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему, у вас какое-то непонимание принципа работы питоновских модулей. А вот это `path.append(getcwd()+"/plugins")` - вообще ересь какая-то.

Думаю вам нужно прочитать [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) и [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) заодно.

> Если я всё правильно понимаю - то это нечто схожее с php. То есть класс объявлен в одном файле, например в файле - `class.php` , а наследуется в файле `extend_class.php`. При таком формате если я в файле `index.php` делаю `include("class.php");` а затем - `include("extend_class.php");` - то мы можем спокойно наследовать класс.
> Как подобное можно реализовать в Python?

[foo.py](http://foo.py):

```
class FooClass:
    pass
```

[extend_foo.py](http://extend_foo.py):

```
import foo

class BarClass(foo.FooClass):
    pass
```

[index.py](http://index.py):

```
import foo, extend_foo

obj1 = foo.FooClass()
obj2 = extend_foo.BarClass()
```

Comment: благодарю..
что касается - path.append(getcwd()+"/plugins")
если Вы знаете как можно импортировать напрямую из папки, не добавляя эту папку - подскажите как. Структура проекта - такая:
./
./app.py (инициализация программы и запуск Loader'а из файла ./plugins/ploader.py)
./plugins/ (каталог эталонных классов для наследования + плагины)
./plugins/ploader.py (инициализатор плагинов)
./plugins/common_thread.py (эталонный класс, который необходимо наследовать)
./plugins/<plugin_name>/<plagin_name>.py ( класс плагина, который наследует эталонный класс и инициализируется в ./plugins/ploader.py)

Comment: > если Вы знаете как можно импортировать напрямую из папки, не добавляя эту папку - подскажите как.

Первая ссылка в сообщении.

Comment: Благодарю, Вы очень помогли!